# Can you explain this sed one-liner?

Tags: linux, unix, sed

The following one liner prints out the content of the file in reverse

```
$ sed -n '1!G;h;$p' test.txt
```

How is it possible when sed reads the file line by line? Can you explain the meaning of

- `n` flag
- `1!`
- `G`
- `h`
- and `$p`

in this command?

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-7-examples-for-sed-hold-and-pattern-buffer-operations/

Comment: Why did you delete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936151/piping-bash-input-arguments-in-egreps-regular-expression ? I thought it was a good question and it got a good answer.

Comment: N.B. an alternative way to write this is `sed '1!G;h;$!d'`

Comment: @sarnold oh sorry about that. I thought I deleted it before any answer was posted. It worked once I put the quotation mark around egrep's pattern. Can you share your insights on this?

Comment: @Alby: Don't forget to vote to undelete, if you haven't already. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do the same job as `tac`, i.e. revert the order of rows.
Rewriting the sed script to pseudocode, it means:

```
$line_number = 1;
foreach ($input in $input_lines) {
    // current input line is in $input
    if ($line_number != 1)               // 1!
        $input = $input + '\n' + $hold;  // G

    $hold = $input; // h

    $line_number++
} 

print $input; // $p
```

As you can see, the sed language is very expressive :-) the `1!` and `$` are so called addresses, which put conditions when the command should be run. `1!` means not on the first row, `$` means at the end. Sed has one auxiliary memory register which is called `hold space`.

For more information type `info sed` on linux console (this is the best documentation).

`-n` disables the default `print $input` command in the loop itself.

The terms `pattern space` and `hold space` are equivalents of the variables `$input` and `$hold` (respectively) in this example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! amazing explanation

Comment: Thanks @Alby - just added a note regarding the `-n` command option, and added a note on pattern/hold space.

Comment: Your pseudocode still has sygils on variables? Get professional help. :) :) :)

Comment: @Kaz: it's even worse; he uses `$input_lines` where he should use `@input_lines`. ;-P

Comment: @ninjalj: not in PHP :-) Let's call it pseudo PHP :-) (with a tinge of javascript :-))

Comment: @Tomas: _not in PHP_ ← that was kind of my point. OTOH, if I have to explain the joke,... I guess it was too subtle.

Answer (score 6):

```
n flag -> Disable auto-printing.
1!     -> Any line except the first one.
G      -> Append a newline and content of 'hold space' to 'pattern space'
h      -> Replace content of 'hold space' with content of 'pattern space'
$      -> Last line.
p      -> print
```

So, it means: Reverse the content of your file, as I understand it.

---

**EDIT** to add some explanation (thanks to ***potong***, see his comment for the original one):

Addresses, like `1` and `$` are bound to next commands, grouped using `{...}` or single without them. So in this case `1!` applies to `G` and `$` to `p`, whereas `h` is not attached to an address and applies to all addresses. That is `$!G` and `$!{G}` are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask what "hold space" and "pattern space" are?

Comment: @Alby: in `sed`, you usually work with the pattern space (e.g: you do substitutions on the pattern space), which holds the line read from the input. There is also a hold space, where you can explicitly store (hold) and retrieve things, to allow for more complex sed scripts.

Comment: I think you should point out when an address is referenced the following command(s) is/are bound to it and that commands can be grouped using `{...}`. So that both `1!` applies to `G` and `$` applies to `p` whereas `h` is not attached to an address and applies to all addresses. Also if a single command follows an address it need not be grouped by bounding `{...}`. That is `$!G` and `$!{G}` are the same.