# piping bash input arguments in egrep's regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, variables, grep

here is the script that I am trying to run

```
#!/bin/bash

charlist=$1 #possible input:cat
wordlength=$2 #possible input: 3

cat ./nounlist | egrep \b[${charlist}]\b{${wordlength}}
```

output: nothing.# should've caught the following(using command line)

```
$ cat nounlist | egrep "\b[cat]{3}\b"
act
cat's_cradle
cat
cat-o'-nine-tails
cat's-paw
Sno-cat
act
act
act
act
rat-a-tat-tat
cat
cat's-claw
cat's_foot
cat's-ear
cat's-tail
cat's-ear
cat's_eye
```

basically I am trying to write a script that takes two arguments(wordlist, wordlength) and fetch all the words in the nounlist that consist of the char in the wordlist and has the length of wordlength variable. What I want to know is how to put bash variables in egrep's regular expression as strings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the argument in double-quotes so that Bash doesn't try to handle the backslashes, and move the second `\b` to *after* the `{${wordlength}}`:

```
cat ./nounlist | egrep "\b[${charlist}]{${wordlength}}\b"
```

(If you run `echo \b`, you'll see that it just prints `b`. This is because Bash assumes that the `\` is there to prevent `b` from having any special meaning; so it removes it.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! just out of curiosity, do bash variables have precedence for all the programs in the bash script? In other words, how do you make sure that ${variable} is bash variable?  and what about the reverse? say you have $1 in the regular expression for sed within the bash script? I have always been curious about this..

Comment: @Alby: Bash will expand `${variable}` if it's not quoted at all (e.g. `echo ${variable}`) or if it's only inside double-quotes (e.g. `echo "${variable}"`). It will *not* expand `${variable}` if it's quoted by a backslash (e.g. `echo \${variable}` or `echo "\${variable}"`) or by single-quotes (e.g. `echo '${variable}'`). For this and related reasons, when you write a `sed` one-liner -- or `awk` one-liner or `perl` one-liner or whatnot -- you usually want to wrap it in single-quotes, so as to minimize Bash's interference with it.